# How to add more lines to toast message

Tags: android, ios, react-native, toast, lib

I am using react-native-toast-message for display error, success and info messages in my app. The Android version of my app can dispay more than 2 lines for the text1 prop, but the iOS can't. I create a variable to be the number of lines depending on the text passed as the text1 prop, but the iOS version still doesn't work. You can have more info bellow.

##### Expected behavior

I'd like the toast to grow in height and number of lines depending on the number of caracters that there are in the text.

##### Steps to reproduce

- Create a customized error toast as specified in the code bellow;
- Try throwing errors that use the error toast with different number of
  lines, for both Android and iOS.

##### Code sample

This is how I am making the number of lines be compatible with the size of text:

```
// Basic
import React from 'react';
import {BaseToast} from 'react-native-toast-message';

// Assets
import styles from './styles';

const ErrorToast = props => {
  const number_of_lines = Math.ceil(props.text1?.length / 30) ?? 1;

  return (
    <BaseToast
      contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
      style={styles.box}
      text1Style={styles.title}
      text1NumberOfLines={number_of_lines}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};

export default ErrorToast;
```

This is the style:

```
import {Dimensions, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import colors from '../../../global/colors';
import fonts from '../../../global/fonts';

const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  box: {
    borderLeftColor: colors.red,
    width: width - 20,
  },
  container: {
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
  },
  title: {
    color: 'black',
    fontFamily: fonts.bold700,
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    lineHeight: 20,
  },
});

export default styles;
```

##### Environment

- OS: [iOS, Android];
- react-native-toast-message version: ^2.1.5;
- react-native version: 0.64.2.